# Cannot retrieve data from Strawpoll API

Tags: python, json, api

I have a simple python code that goes to [this link](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=googleplex&sensor=false) and retrieves it's data. Here is the code

```
import urllib, json
url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=googleplex&sensor=false"
htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(htmlfile.read())
print data
```

Running the code returns the data from the url.

```
{u'status': u'ZERO_RESULTS', u'results': []}
```

I'd like to do the same, but for Strawpoll. After reading through their [API documentation](https://github.com/strawpoll/strawpoll/wiki/API), it appears to be the same formula. Going to the strawpoll link for testing, it shows me the same content structure as the google link shown above. The API Documenation states that " All resources will return data in JSON." But I am not getting any data back, I'm getting errors. The code is exactly the same, but with the edited url.

```
import urllib, json
url = "http://strawpoll.me/api/v2/polls/1/"
htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(htmlfile.read())
print data
```

Running the code gives me a view errors, I would post an image but stackoverflow won't let me...

The last error I receive is "ValueError: No JSON object could be loaded". But the API Documentation said that data is returned as JSON.

Removing the `json.loads` gives me pure html instead. Here is the code for that. Again, exactly the same but removed the `json.loads`.

```
import urllib
url = "http://strawpoll.me/api/v2/polls/1/"
htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = htmlfile.read()
print data
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran your code and looked into the HTML response. Perhaps you are not setting the right HTTP headers? It says that access is denied, but I'm not sure why that would be. I'd recommend using [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

```
>>> url = "http://strawpoll.me/api/v2/polls/1/"
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get(url).json()
{u'id': 1, u'multi': False, u'votes': [14683, 31165, 5635, 7397], u'options': [u'Sucker punch ', u'Pirates of carribian ', u'Prison logic', u'Witchhunter'], u'title': u'What movie should we watch'}
```

Since you are not opening the URL from a browser, it could be an effort by strawpoll.me to protect their content from being scraped. In fact, I found this line in the HTML response:

```
<p>The owner of this website (strawpoll.me) has banned your access based on your browser's signature (***).</p>
```

Comment: That works! Thank you.

 Maybe it has to do with the way that Strawpoll is configured? Mhmm oh well. Thanks again for your help!